# Azure DevOps - Pass Powershell list variable to yml template array

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, yaml

I want to generate a list in a Powershell task as an output variable and use it in a yml template as a list to perform a loop for a task.

```
#Main
- task: PowerShell@2
  condition: succeeded()
  displayName: "Create a list"
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |

      $myList = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

      $myList.Add("wow")

      Write-Output ("##vso[task.setvariable variable=MyList;]$myList")

- template: myRandomListTaskTemplate.yml
  parameters:
      MyList: $(MyList)


#Template
parameters:
  MyList: []

steps:

- ${{ each myList in parameters.MyList }}:
    - task: PowerShell@2
      condition: succeeded()
      displayName: "WOW a list"
      inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: |
            Write-Host("A list string: ${{ myList }}")
```

I am getting the error

```
Expected a sequence or mapping. Actual value '$(MyList)'
```

Note: The Powershell Task in the Template is just an example, it can be other Tasks that are not Powershell related (example: DotNetCoreCLI@2)

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question,  If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: Hi @LeoLiu-MSFT, im still trying to find a way to achieve this.

Comment: I'm really sorry, I thought I posted my answer, but I seem to have forgotten it. Hope this late answer can give you any help, please check if my answer give any helps, have a nice day.

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question,  If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It will not work as you expect.

```
$myList = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

$myList.Add("wow")

Write-Output ("##vso[task.setvariable variable=MyList;]$myList")
```

You are not going here to have an array. Once you assign this to variable it will be a plain string. This is why you are getting this error.

If you run this:

```yaml
- template: myRandomListTaskTemplate2.yml
  parameters:
    MyList: 
    - item1
    - item2
```

all went fine. However, it is not possible to do what you at the moment.

Please check [this developer community topic](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/812728/variables-in-yaml-pipeline-are-not-allowing-to-def.html).